# native crash on SM-J410G, android 8.1

Tags: android, android-8.1-oreo

I made some research and was not able to understand what could be the reason of this crash.
Does anyone have a clue? thanks!!

Here are some logs . It only crash on the devices, SM-J410G android 8.1

---

pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.app99.driver <<<

backtrace:
#00 pc 000000000001a70e /system/lib/libc.so (abort+63)
#00 pc 00000000000065a1 /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+156)
#00 pc 000000000002fe31 /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::debug::GlesErrorCheckWrapper::assertNoErrors(char const*)+192)
#00 pc 000000000005c02d /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::Caches::flush(android::uirenderer::Caches::FlushMode)+116)
#00 pc 000000000004f835 /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::Bridge_destroyHardwareResources(android::uirenderer::renderthread::destroyHardwareResourcesArgs*)+4)
#00 pc 0000000000050233 /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::MethodInvokeRenderTask::run()+10)
#00 pc 00000000000503b3 /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::SignalingRenderTask::run()+10)
#00 pc 0000000000051103 /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+178)
#00 pc 000000000000d23d /system/lib/libutils.so (android::_threadLoop(void*)+144)
#00 pc 0000000000068f89 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+80)
#00 pc 00000000000479df /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
#00 pc 000000000001b2dd /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)